# Creating an Add-In to click on an ArcFM function

Tags: add-in, arcfm

I would like to create an add-in to press ArcFM save every five minutes. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing you can use a timer that calls a UID save command every five min. here is a Q/A that shows how to use UID save edit command http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25103/how-do-i-save-edits-from-an-arcmap-editing-session-using-vb-net

Comment: I'm guessing I can write this code to an add-in for ArcMap, or would I need to create an object?

Comment: Yes, you can write the code as an add-in for ArcMap.